# Swapping first letters of different words

Tags: word-usage

What is it called when you swap the first letters of two words?, for example - red truck is what is intended...instead ted ruck is what comes out.

Answer (score 4):

[spoonerism](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/spoonerism) - noun - A verbal error in which a speaker accidentally transposes the initial sounds or letters of two or more words, often to humorous effect

e.g. "You have hissed the mystery lectures," accidentally spoken instead of the intended sentence "you have missed the history lectures."

Comment: Named after the Reverend Spooner, if I recall correctly.